# Error "Invalid call to qualifier on unresolved object" when trying to write a Spark DF into a Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

I am having the error "`Invalid call to qualifier on unresolved object, tree: 'date1`" when trying to write a specific Spark DataFrame into a Hive table.

I am using Spark 2.4.0, but also tested in Spark 2.4.3 with the same result.

I know how to avoid the error, but **none of these methods are the expected solution because it modifies the table somehow**:

- Deleting 1 column from `PARTITIONED BY` in the create table code.
- Moving the position of column `text3` just after `text2`.
- In the df, creating `boolean1` column as a `string` type instead of `boolean` one (don't need to change the type in Hive table).
- Deleting 1 of the columns in df and table (df and table must have the same number of columns):

  - Obviously, deleting `date1` column as is the one given by the error message.
  - Deleting column `text3`.

Except deleting the `date1` column, no other method makes sense to me. I don't understand why by applying any of those options it fixes the problem.

This is a **Scala sample code** in order to reproduce the error:

```
// Create a sample dataframe
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("",
              "",
              false,
              "",
              "2019-07-01"))
    .toDF("text1",
          "text2",
          "boolean1",
          "text3",
          "date1")

// df schema:
df.printSchema
root
 |-- text1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- text2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- boolean1: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- text3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date1: string (nullable = true)

// Create the related hive table
spark.sql("drop table if exists table_sample")
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE `table_sample` (
    `text1` STRING,
    `text2` STRING, 
    `boolean1` BOOLEAN, 
    `text3` STRING,
    `date1` DATE
    )
USING ORC
PARTITIONED BY (text1, text2)
""")

// Write the sample dataframe to the hive table
df.write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("orc")
      .insertInto("table_sample")
```

I expect the table can be created with no error and without needing to change the table schema (not renaming columns, changing columns types or moving columns into another position).

This is the full stacktrace:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException: Invalid call to qualifier on unresolved object, tree: 'trx_business_day_date
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute.qualifier(unresolved.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq$$anonfun$3.apply(package.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq$$anonfun$3.apply(package.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq.<init>(package.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$.AttributeSeq(package.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.outputAttributes$lzycompute(LogicalPlan.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.outputAttributes(LogicalPlan.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:102)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:94)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$analyzed$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$analyzed$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$output$1(QueryExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:325)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:9)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:134)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:136)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:138)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:140)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:142)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:144)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:146)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:148)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:150)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:152)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:154)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:156)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:158)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:160)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:162)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:164)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:166)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:168)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:170)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:172)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:174)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:176)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:178)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:180)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:182)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:184)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:186)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:188)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:190)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:192)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:194)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:196)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:198)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:200)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:202)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:204)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:206)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:208)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1106698602130938:210)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read.<init>(command-1106698602130938:212)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$.<init>(command-1106698602130938:216)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$read$.<clinit>(command-1106698602130938)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line694971ab74ea4d1382bf12d864e23292142.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:199)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:587)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:542)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$7.apply(DriverLocal.scala:324)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$7.apply(DriverLocal.scala:304)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:304)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:584)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:475)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:542)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:328)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anyone knows how can I fix the problem without changing the df/table schema? Can it be a Spark bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you do your df.printSchema i suspect the date1 column is string and not date.  if so convert the column using to_date and see if you are able to insert.

Comment: You are right about `date1` being `String` and not `date`. I have changed the code adding the casting and it doesn't work either. The problem was my misunderstanding of `insertInto`, as [it ignores the column names and just uses position-based resolution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter). Gopal answered correctly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Real issue is that your code is trying to insert boolean value 'false' in date1 column where date1 is 'Date' type.

Solution for your problem will be moving the partitioned columns as last two columns in dataframe df. 
As spark's .insertInto() method treats last columns as partitioned columns. It will not match it on column names in dataframe instead it works on index based column mapping.

Below df works perfectly without changing table structure.

```
val df = Seq(( false,"","2019-07-01","", ""))
  .toDF(
    "boolean1", "text3", "date1", "text1", "text2")
```

Query: "Show create table table_sample" resulted as

```
CREATE TABLE `table_sample` (`boolean1` BOOLEAN, `text3` STRING, `date1` DATE, `text1` STRING, `text2` STRING)
USING ORC
OPTIONS (
`serialization.format` '1'
)
PARTITIONED BY (text1, text2)
```

So according to above table structure and your dataframe df the mapping done by spark will be:

```
`boolean1` BOOLEAN = "" 
`text3` STRING     = ""
`date1` DATE       = false         --> Issue is this mapping
`text1` STRING     = ""
`text2` STRING     = "2019-07-01"
```

It could be a Spark bug too as it should insert null in date field instead of throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding about [insertInto](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@insertInto(tableName:String):Unit). I did not remember that `insertInto` ignores the column names and get fields by position.
Anyway, I have been doing some testing and I prefer using saveAsTable. Thanks very much @Gopal!

Comment: @rvilla No Problem. Also you are correct with insertInto as its a index based mapping. Happy coding :) . Upvote to the answer might help.

Comment: I did it but I had 14 reputation and I couldn't vote. Just now with 18 reputation I can vote and I have just done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error when I am trying to create the table while there was a pre-existing table with same name but slightly different schema types. I had to drop the preexisting table to correct this error.